# Excel formula to find a number within a range of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

EDIT, in short:

I have an excel table that looks like this:

[tabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CejnZ.png)

Each cell contains a range of numbers.
I'm looking for a function that can search for a number in the whole table and indicate me the column and row where the range that it belongs to is located.

So, if I search for number 2346, it should function like this:

function (2346) > result (C1, R2)

---

I have a huge archive of photos (about 300.000 items) in a library.
Photos are stored in boxes, the boxes in shelves.
Each box has a range of inventory numbers of photos.

I want to create a map of the deposit that looks like this:

Shelf 1 - contains boxes 1, 2, 3, etc.
Box 1 - contains photos with inventory numbers between 1257-1321
Box 2 -"- between 2345-2522
Box 3 -"- between 123523-123643

Translated in an excel table, it would look like this:

Column 1 would be Shelf 1, containing the boxes with the images:
cell in column 1 / row 1 (that's box 1) contains the range of numbers: 1257-1321
cell in column 1 / row 2 (box 2), the range: 2345-2522
cell in column 1 / row 3 (box 3), range: 123523-123643

They are not in order, because they entered in more than 100 years in the collection, and they are arranged as they entered and by subject. Not to mention that the deposit has been moved a few times. So, I have a hard time to find one image when I'm looking for it.

But if I have this excel table, this map of the deposit, supposedly I want to enter the inventory number that I'm looking for, let's say "2346", and a formula that search throughout the whole table would indicate me that the item (number I look for, is in a range that is located in column 1, row 2, that means shelf one, box 2 in the deposit).

Actually the concept is very simple, excel is able to do MUCH more difficult tasks, and I'm amazed I can't find a way to do this. I'm a photographer and librarian, so my experience in programming is close to zero.

Thank you very much if you can help!

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data in markdown format? You can use [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) online tool for example. Make life a little easier :). It's also good practice to include your own effort and let us know what about that didn't work as expected. Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] and rework your question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a lenghty one but not hard to understand, I made some sample data like so:

[image]

```
="C"&SUMPRODUCT(((VALUE(LEFT($A$1:$B$3,SEARCH("-",$A$1:$B$3)-1))<=D3)*(VALUE(RIGHT($A$1:$B$3,LEN($A$1:$B$3)-SEARCH("-",$A$1:$B$3)))>=D3))*COLUMN($A$1:$B$3))&", "&"R"&SUMPRODUCT(((VALUE(LEFT($A$1:$B$3,SEARCH("-",$A$1:$B$3)-1))<=D3)*(VALUE(RIGHT($A$1:$B$3,LEN($A$1:$B$3)-SEARCH("-",$A$1:$B$3)))>=D3))*ROW($A$1:$B$3))
```

Youll just have to change ranges

Comment: OMG! This is perfect!
Implementing and working like a charm!
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @DragosAndriana, I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your worksheet like the image below (sheet name "Library"):

[image]

You could try the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Painting()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, SearchValue As Long
    Dim arrData As Variant

    'Let s say that all data appears in sheet called Library
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Library")

        'Let s say that we are looking for the value in cell H1
        SearchValue = .Range("H1").Value

        'Find the Last row of column A sheet Library
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Create as array from Column A row 2 up to Column D row LastRow
        arrData = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 4)).Value

        'Loop Array to find a match
        For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)

            If arrData(i, 3) <= SearchValue And arrData(i, 4) >= SearchValue Then
                'Pop up with Shelf & Box name
                MsgBox "Search Value " & SearchValue & " included in:" & vbNewLine & "Shelf: " & arrData(i, 1) & vbNewLine & "Box: " & arrData(i, 2)
                'Select the line where the Search Value found
                .Range("A" & i + 1 & ":D" & i + 1).Select
                'Exit the loop
                Exit For
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]